# How do I mix custom parameter binding with dependency injection in Azure Functions?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, parameters, azure-functions

I have an Azure Functions app that uses custom parameter bindings that were initialised in the [WebJobsStartup] - how do I migrate these to the new **[FunctionsStartup]** way of doing things?

In the [WebJobsStartup] the bindings were registered by the call to builder.AddExtension with .AddBindingRule

Now the new Azure SDK says to use [FunctionsStartup] - how do I hook in (or replace) **.AddBindingRule** in this?

The FunctionsStartup implementation looks like:-

```cs
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(EventSourcingOnAzureFunctions.Common.Startup))]
namespace EventSourcingOnAzureFunctions.Common
{
    public class Startup
        : FunctionsStartup
    {

        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {

            builder.AddAppSettingsToConfiguration();

            // Initialise any common services
            CQRSAzureBindings.InitializeServices(builder.Services);

            builder.Services.AddWebJobs(ConfigureWebJobs  );

        }

        public void ConfigureWebJobs(JobHostOptions hostOptions)
        {

        }
}
```

And the way it used to register the binding rules is like:-

```cs
        /// <summary>
        /// Initailise any common dependency injection configuration settings
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        public static void InitializeInjectionConfiguration(ExtensionConfigContext context)
        {


            // Set up the dependency injection stuff for the custom bindings 
            // 1: EventStream
            context
                .AddBindingRule<EventStreamAttribute>()
                .BindToInput<EventStream>(BuildEventStreamFromAttribute)
                ;
         }
```

If I run the function app as is the binding rules code does not get called and as a result the function indexing fails with e.g.

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'DepositMoney'. 
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot bind parameter
>   'bankAccountEvents' to type EventStream.  Make sure the parameter Type
>   is supported by the binding.  If you're using binding extensions (e.g.
>   Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the
>   registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g.
>   builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(),
>   builder.AddTimers(), etc.).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get an instance of [WebJobsStartup] to call builder.AddExtension in your Startup.cs

In my case, I need to use an extension from a NuGet package

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Kafka;
```

But I passed through the same case as you, but finally, I made it work :)

```
[assembly: 
FunctionsStartup(typeof(EventSourcingOnAzureFunctions.Common.Startup))]
namespace EventSourcingOnAzureFunctions.Common
{
    public class Startup
    : FunctionsStartup
    {

        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            var serviceProvider = builders.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
            var env = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHostEnvironment>();
            var appDirectory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<ExecutionContextOptions>>().Value.AppDirectory;

            // IWebJobsBuilders instance
            var wbBuilder = builder.Services.AddWebJobs(x => { return; });
            wbBuilder.AddKafka();

            // And now you can use AddExtension
            // wbBuilder.AddExtension

        }
 }
```

Comment: What `builder.Services.AddWebJobs(x => { return; })` does? Is it creating extra web job?

Answer (score 6):

To do this you would have two separate startup classes.  One that inherits from FunctionsStartup and the other that implements the IWebJobsStartup interface.  The WebJobsStartup runs first, then the FunctionsStartup.

Here's how I tested it.

**WebJobsStartup class**

```
namespace CustomBinding
{
    public class WebJobsStartup : IWebJobsStartup
    {
        void IWebJobsStartup.Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("WebJobsStartup.Configure");
        }
    }
}
```

**AssemblyInfo class**

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting;

[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(CustomBinding.WebJobsStartup))]
```

**Startup Class**

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(CustomBinding.Startup))]

namespace CustomBinding
{

    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("FunctionsStartup.Configure");
        }        
    }   
}
```